# Javascript : problem with 'this'

Tags: javascript

Here is a piece of code

```
function test() {
    this.value = "foo";       
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    test();
    alert(this.value);   //--> return undefined
    alert(window.value); //--> return 'foo'
});
```

Can someone explain me those results ?

Regards

Salvatore

Comment: Could you please mark one of the answers as correct?

Answer (score 7):

In your function `test()`, `this` is refferring to the `DOMWindow`

In the `$(document).ready()` function, `this` was referring to `document`.

So since in `test()` you set the window's value, that is why `window.value ==> 'foo'`, but `document.value ==> undefined`

[Read this article on function scope which might help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)

Comment: Just for fun, try this: `window["blarg"] = 42; alert(blarg)`. this is because all "global variables" are actually properties of the root object (`window`). So your second alert could have been `alert(value)` instead of `alert(window.value)`.

Comment: @Salvatore, remember to pick an `accepted answer` when you can

Comment: @NaftaliakaNeal I was surprised of '$(document).ready()' to refer to the 'document' object, in my mind I think the code for document ready to be like:

function ready(callback) {
  callback()
}

but it seams bound to the 'document' object.

Is this beacase the selector '$(document)' force to be binded the "events callbacks" to that object?

I don't remember a lot of 'jquery' but I was just intrigued.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a complicated keyword to get your head around.

I advise reading through this, it may help a bit more http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

**Edit:** I also believe that your `this.value` problem is caused because of scoping. Your function has an entirely different scope to your jQuery `document.ready(..)` one.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's `this` works differently according to how the function is called.

Rather than explaining it all myself, I'll point you to this article, which covers it in excellent detail: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this

Answer (score 0):

```
function test() 
{ 
      this.value = "foo"; // this is window
}

 $(document).ready(function () {
    test();
    alert(this.value);   //--> this is window.document
    alert(window.value); //--> return 'foo'
});
```

Comment: This is wrong, `this` in the `.ready()` scope is referring to `document`

Comment: is document not a property of window?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to jquery but the solution should be simple:

```
 $(document).ready(...)
```

attach the function used as parameter to the event onReady of the document object.
The context of the function should be the document or the event (depends on the framework you use).

We can analize the onReady function body starting from the line

```
 alert(this.value);   //--> return undefined
```

return undefined as the element pointed from this does not have that properties.

The trick lies into the line

```
test();
```

You may think that the *this* keyword into the test function body refers to the context of the outer function but javascript is *lexycally scoped* and the context of a function is
defined at the time the function is declared instead that at the time of the function is called.

Saying that you can think that the function is a global one and then the this keyword it address is the function itself (in javascript a function is an object too) and then how is it that test pollute the window object as clearly indicate by the line

```
alert(window.value); //--> return 'foo'
```

?

When you call a function (not a method or a constructor) or a it behaves as it is a method of the *window* object and then in the test function you are defining the value property of the window object.

The complete picture is a bit more complex but theese are the basics